# Regular expression to match 3 capital letters followed by a small letter followed by 3 capital letters?

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression in python which matches exactly 3 capital letters followed by a small letter followed by exactly 3 capital letters.
For example, it should match ASDfGHJ and not ASDFgHJK.

Comment: Hilarious.  I was just looking at part 3 of http://www.pythonchallenge.com and a search for "python re capital letter" points to this page.  Looks like the OP was trying to cheat...  The frustrating thing is that I'm still not sure how to use the answer to get to part 4...

Comment: Try and focus on the whole words you find combined, and not just find one which is the answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
r'\b[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}\b'
```

This will match what you posted if it is a complete word.

```
r'(?<![^A-Z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])'
```

This will match what you posted so long as it's not preceded or followed by another capital letter.

Comment: Note that this will not match all Unicode uppercase letters, for instance, it won't match `u"Ů"`

Answer (score 2):

here it is:

```
'[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3}'
```

**Edited**
you need to use word boundary also:

```
r'\b[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3}\b'
```

Comment: This will match his counterexample, `ASDFgHJK`. Also, the `{1}` is unnecessary.

Comment: It'll match ASDFgHJK. I don't need that as given in the example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that this will not match all Unicode uppercase letters, for instance, it won't match `u"Ů"`

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r'[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z]', data)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: re is regex for anyone else coming to this, so you have to import re

Comment: Note that this will not match all Unicode uppercase letters, for instance, it won't match `u"Ů"`

Answer (score 0):

This is will check that one small character is exactly present between 3 capital characters on both sides.

I have used lookahead and lookbehind to ensure that exactly three capital characters are on both sides.

```
r'(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])'.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'^[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-z]'
>>> re.match(pattern , "ABCaABC").start()
    0
>>> print re.match(pattern , "ABCABC")
    None
>>> print re.match(pattern , "ABCAABC")
    None
>>> print re.match(pattern , "ABCAaABC")
    None
>>> print re.match(pattern , "ASDFgHJK")
    None
>>> print re.match(pattern , "ABCaABC")
    <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x011ECF70>
```

`r'^[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-z]'`
^ ->Start with capital, so First three letters must be capital.

Comment: You don't need the `{1}`, and he wants the lowercase letter followed by __exactly__ three capital letters.

Comment: Note that this will not match all Unicode uppercase letters, for instance, it won't match `u"Ů"`